# Push notifications not working on macOS Catalyst app

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

After switching my bundle identifier from the one automatically generated for a Catalyst app to the bundle ID of an existing Mac app, I am no longer receiving remote push notifications.

The app shows that it is registered for notifications. The topic on the server is set to the correct bundle ID (the bundle ID Of the existing Mac app). I’ve tried with a JWT token and with Mac push certificates.

The response from the server returns 200 “sent”, but I’m not receiving the notification on my device.

Has anyone gotten push notifications working with a Catalyst app not using the auto-generated bundle ID? Any ideas on stuff I could try to get this working?

Comment: To follow up on this, the push notifications were working the whole time - I realized something was wrong when local notifications weren't appearing either, so when I rebooted all the notifications (local and push) were in notification center.

Comment: Another follow-up: now I'm back to not getting any push notifications at all.

Comment: I don't think the catalyst tag is correct.

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: Facing the exact same issue

Comment: @gpichler I think the issue may have been that I wasn't setting the new apns push type field, which is now required for push notifications - as that's one thing that changed in between me posting this question and it starting to work in my app.

Comment: @bmueller thanks for that very good guess. Just checked on our server and we are already setting the `push-type-field`. However, we are not able to receive pushes on macOS (catalyst).

Answer (score 0):

We used the auto-generated bundle id and initially had problems with notifications.
Now we have to use the iOS app bundle id to send notifications to the Mac Catalyst app. From memory this didn't work when we tried it a few months ago and we filed a bug.
I suggest using the iOS app bundle id even though you are using a custom bundle id.